# testing if proper route is called after clicking on a button

Tags: angularjs, angular, jasmine, karma-jasmine, router

I'm new to unit testing, tried reading several tuorials as how to test ng2 components, routers etc.. But still I'm no wiser as how to accomplish this.

I'd like to test whether the "login" route is activated after clicking on `#logout` button.

Here's what I got so far, but it's <s>not working at all</s> partially working. When I call the `spy.calls.first()` I get `undefined`, however when I call `spy.calls.all()` I can see the expected result.

```
import { ComponentFixture, TestBed, inject } from '@angular/core/testing';
import { By }              from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';
import { DebugElement }    from '@angular/core';
import { async } from '@angular/core/testing';

import { HomeComponent } from './home.component';

import { click } from '../testing/index'

class RouterStub {
  navigate(url: string) { return url; }
}

describe('HomeComponent', () => {

  let comp:    HomeComponent;
  let fixture: ComponentFixture<HomeComponent>;
  let de:      DebugElement;
  let el:      HTMLElement;
  let logoutBtnEl: HTMLElement;

  // async beforeEach
  beforeEach( async(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      declarations: [ HomeComponent ], // declare the test component
      providers: [
        { provide: Router,      useClass: RouterStub }
      ]
    })
    .compileComponents();  // compile template and css
  }));


  // synchronous beforeEach
  beforeEach(() => {
    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(HomeComponent);
    comp = fixture.componentInstance; // BannerComponent test instance

    de = fixture.debugElement.query(By.css('h1'));  // query for the title <h1> by CSS element selector
    el = de.nativeElement;
    logoutBtnEl = fixture.debugElement.query(By.css('#logout')).nativeElement;
    fixture.detectChanges(); // trigger initial data binding
  });

  it('should display contain \'Welcome\' in title', () => {
    expect(el.textContent).toContain("Welcome");
  });

  it('should tell ROUTER to navigate when logout clicked',
    inject([Router], (router: Router) => {
        const spy = spyOn(router, 'navigate');
        click(logoutBtnEl);
        console.log(spy.calls.first())
        const navArgs = spy.calls.first().args[0];
        expect( navArgs ).toBe('login', 'should nav to login screen')
    }
  ));


});
```

Comment: Why don't you just use `expect(spy.navigate).toHaveBeenCalledWith(['login'])`?

Comment: well that's a good point indeed :] ..

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:

Use: `RouterTestingModule`:

```
import { RouterTestingModule } from '@angular/router/testing';
```

Import it:

```
imports: [
                etc...,
                RouterTestingModule
            ],
```

Then test it:

```
let component: DashboardComponent;

it ('should be able to go to login on click', () => {
        spyOn(component.router, 'navigate').and.returnValue(true);
        component.logout();
        expect(component.router.navigate).toHaveBeenCalledWith(['login']);
    });
```